# Very generic error while trying to build for iOS

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I have just installed Cordova (version 6.1.1) on a Mac running ElCaptain (version 10.11.5) with Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014).

I am just following the 'get started' steps but when I try to run `$cordova build ios` I get a very generic error message

```
$ Error:
```

with no explanation or detail whatsoever.

On the contrary, if I try to build for android the whole thing works.

Any suggestion on how to try to understand what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its very difficult to narrow down the problem unless you give more info like your config.xml, project structure etc.

Comment: I understand that my question may sound silly but the problem arises with an almost empty app. I have performed these simple steps: 1) `$cordova create test` 2) `$cd test` 3) `$cordova platform add ios` 4) `$cordova build ios`. I did not do anything more, and therefore i think is a problem of version compatibility, but I am totally ignorant so I hope somebody has encountered a similar issue

Comment: You are using cordova CLI rite? EI Captain (10.11.3) with XCode 7.3.1 and cordova 6.1.1 works fine for me

Comment: Yes, I am using CLI. I will try to reinstall Xcode and cross-fingers. Thx

Comment: I doubt reinstalling xcode will help. Could be something to do with nodejs and npm?

Comment: I am facing the same issue today. Did anyone found a solution.

Comment: I remember I have solved the problem by having Xcode open up and running, but I can not reproduce the case now